# Accessing App in web browser creating by "refinerycms" in linux machine?

Tags: ruby, linux, browser, refinerycms, linux-mint

I have Created a app "my_new_app" in my linux terminal like as follow :

```
u107@mint107 ~ $ refinerycms /home/u107/my_new_app
      create  
      create  README.rdoc
      create  Rakefile
      create  config.ru
      create  .gitignore
      create  Gemfile
      create  app
      create  app/assets/images/rails.png
      create  app/assets/javascripts/application.js
      create  app/assets/stylesheets/application.css
      create  app/controllers/application_controller.rb
      create  app/helpers/application_helper.rb
      create  app/mailers
      create  app/models
      create  app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
      create  app/mailers/.gitkeep
      create  app/models/.gitkeep
      create  config
      create  config/routes.rb
      create  config/application.rb
      create  config/environment.rb
      create  config/environments
      create  config/environments/development.rb
      create  config/environments/production.rb
      create  config/environments/test.rb
      create  config/initializers
      create  config/initializers/backtrace_silencers.rb
      create  config/initializers/inflections.rb
      create  config/initializers/mime_types.rb
      create  config/initializers/secret_token.rb
      create  config/initializers/session_store.rb
      create  config/initializers/wrap_parameters.rb
      create  config/locales
      create  config/locales/en.yml
      create  config/boot.rb
      create  config/database.yml
      create  db
      create  db/seeds.rb
      create  doc
      create  doc/README_FOR_APP
      create  lib
      create  lib/tasks
      create  lib/tasks/.gitkeep
      create  lib/assets
      create  lib/assets/.gitkeep
      create  log
      create  log/.gitkeep
      create  public
      create  public/404.html
      create  public/422.html
      create  public/500.html
      create  public/favicon.ico
      create  public/index.html
      create  public/robots.txt
      create  script
      create  script/rails
      create  tmp/cache
      create  tmp/cache/assets
      create  vendor/assets/javascripts
      create  vendor/assets/javascripts/.gitkeep
      create  vendor/assets/stylesheets
      create  vendor/assets/stylesheets/.gitkeep
      create  vendor/plugins
      create  vendor/plugins/.gitkeep
       apply  /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/refinerycms-2.1.0/templates/refinery/installer.rb
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/execjs-2.0.2/lib/execjs/runtimes.rb:51:in `autodetect': Could not find a JavaScript runtime. See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs for a list of available runtimes. (ExecJS::RuntimeUnavailable)
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/execjs-2.0.2/lib/execjs.rb:5:in `<module:ExecJS>'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/execjs-2.0.2/lib/execjs.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:60:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:60:in `rescue in require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:35:in `require'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/refinerycms-2.1.0/templates/refinery/installer.rb:6:in `apply'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.18.1/lib/thor/actions.rb:221:in `instance_eval'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.18.1/lib/thor/actions.rb:221:in `apply'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.15/lib/rails/generators/app_base.rb:109:in `apply_rails_template'
    from (eval):1:in `apply_rails_template'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.18.1/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.18.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:120:in `invoke_command'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.18.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `block in invoke_all'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.18.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `each'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.18.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `map'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.18.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_all'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.18.1/lib/thor/group.rb:233:in `dispatch'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.18.1/lib/thor/base.rb:439:in `start'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/refinerycms-2.1.0/bin/refinerycms:43:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/bin/refinerycms:23:in `load'
    from /usr/local/bin/refinerycms:23:in `<main>'
u107@mint107 ~ $ ^C
u107@mint107 ~ $ cd /home/u107/my_new_app/
u107@mint107 ~/my_new_app $ rails server
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/execjs-2.0.2/lib/execjs/runtimes.rb:51:in `autodetect': Could not find a JavaScript runtime. See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs for a list of available runtimes. (ExecJS::RuntimeUnavailable)
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/execjs-2.0.2/lib/execjs.rb:5:in `<module:ExecJS>'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/execjs-2.0.2/lib/execjs.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/coffee-script-2.2.0/lib/coffee_script.rb:1:in `require'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/coffee-script-2.2.0/lib/coffee_script.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/coffee-script-2.2.0/lib/coffee-script.rb:1:in `require'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/coffee-script-2.2.0/lib/coffee-script.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/coffee-rails-3.2.2/lib/coffee-rails.rb:1:in `require'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/coffee-rails-3.2.2/lib/coffee-rails.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `require'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `each'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `block in require'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `each'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `require'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler.rb:132:in `require'
    from /home/u107/my_new_app/config/application.rb:13:in `<top (required)>'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.15/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `require'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.15/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.15/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.15/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
u107@mint107 ~/my_new_app $
```

A dircetory structure is this :

```
./log
./script
./config
./config/locales
./config/initializers
./config/environments
./lib
./lib/tasks
./lib/assets
./public
./vendor
./vendor/plugins
./vendor/assets
./vendor/assets/stylesheets
./vendor/assets/javascripts
./db
./tmp
./tmp/cache
./tmp/cache/assets
./app
./app/views
./app/views/layouts
./app/helpers
./app/models
./app/assets
./app/assets/images
./app/assets/stylesheets
./app/assets/javascripts
./app/controllers
./app/mailers
./doc
```

so here i got a problem i don't know how to access it in web browser
Please tell me how can i see this app in web browser. 
Please answer rapidly.
Thanks in advance

```
Your bundle is complete!
Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
u107@mint107 ~/my_new_app $ rails server
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/execjs-2.0.2/lib/execjs/runtimes.rb:51:in `autodetect': Could not find a JavaScript runtime. See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs for a list of available runtimes. (ExecJS::RuntimeUnavailable)
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/execjs-2.0.2/lib/execjs.rb:5:in `<module:ExecJS>'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/execjs-2.0.2/lib/execjs.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/coffee-script-2.2.0/lib/coffee_script.rb:1:in `require'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/coffee-script-2.2.0/lib/coffee_script.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/coffee-script-2.2.0/lib/coffee-script.rb:1:in `require'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/coffee-script-2.2.0/lib/coffee-script.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/coffee-rails-3.2.2/lib/coffee-rails.rb:1:in `require'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/coffee-rails-3.2.2/lib/coffee-rails.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `require'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `each'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `block in require'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `each'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `require'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler.rb:132:in `require'
    from /home/u107/my_new_app/config/application.rb:13:in `<top (required)>'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.15/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `require'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.15/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.15/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.15/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the docs, go into your project (the one that has the folders you listed), and run:

`rails server` or `rails s` for short, after you make sure you have bundled.

You can see the docs [here](http://refinerycms.com/guides/getting-started). You can then see it in your browser at `localhost:3000` just like any other ruby web application (as long as you don't use `-b` or `-p` on the `rails server` command. If you do, you must change this url accordingly).

Edit:

According to your update, you need a javascript runtime. You can use `therubyracer`for this, as it is included by default in your `Gemfile` for a rails project most of the time. You should check your `Gemfile` for `gem "therubyracer"` and if it is commented out, uncomment it and re-bundle, then try `rails s` again.

Comment: Sir i have just tried but not worked yet .i have changed question so please see what i got after type rails s

Comment: where i have to check this ? ok got it its in root folder and like as follows :# gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby

Comment: it should be in your project directory, since you can see in the output of the refinerycms: `create  Gemfile` is there.

Comment: here i have to remove # sign only?

Comment: Ok sir now i make it as gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby
alright and i have to start rails s now ?

Comment: No, you must do `bundle install` then `rails s`. I would highly suggest you read http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html to learn more about this process.

Comment: ok that is furthar rails application ? i was taking it as a diffrent framework in ruby